# How to fix page doing 4 extra queries when using easy_thumbnails in combination with Amazon S3?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, thumbnails, easy-thumbnails

I'm setting up Amazon S3 to use as my media server for serving image files. I use [easy_thumbnails](https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails) for thumbnailing the images. easy_thumbnails does the cropping before sending them to S3, therefore storing 4 images with each a different size. Without Amazon S3, the page does 2 queries to load the page. With Amazon S3 it uses 6 queries for the same page. The queries show that the original file is queried as well as the cropped file. This shouldn't be necessary I believe. How can I decrease the amount of requests it does using S3?

This image shows the queries **with** Amazon S3
[image: This image shows the queries with Amazon S3]
[image: This image shows the queries normally]
This image shows the queries **without** Amazon S3

**edit
I noticed easy_thumbnails is not optimized for remote storages according to [django packages](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/thumbnails/). So, an alternative for easy_thumbnails that is optimized would help me as well!

Comment: It seems that your image is cropped before being sent to S3. If you look at the query you can see that the image is pre-processed before the call to AWS S3 storage.

Comment: @Dos True. the image is stored multiple times each with different sizes. Is that causing the problem?

Comment: Yes, at least a query for each size, as the system needs to store and retrieve the image before sending it to S3.

Comment: @Dos is it possible to store just the original image at S3, just do a query for that file and do that cropping while loading the page or is that even worse for performance?

Comment: I don't know how you're using easy_thumbnails, so I suggest you look at the settings docs in order to understand the best configuration for you. Here the link: https://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.io/en/2.1/ref/settings/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like easy_thumbnails requests the same image files everytime the page is loaded (caching that doesn't work for easy_thumbnails maybe). As I read that easy_thumbnails isn't optimized for remote storage I looked for alternatives and tried [sorl-thumbnail](https://github.com/jazzband/sorl-thumbnail). This seems to do the job! It doesn't send request each page load and therefore the amount of queries decreased a lot!